# Why is d5 better than dxe5 in this position?

Tags: strategy

I tried looking at a few lines with the engine but still couldn't quite understand how white managed to obtain a better position in some of the lines. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[Title "White to move"]
[fen "r1bqr1k1/1pp2pp1/p1n2n1p/4p3/3PP3/2PB1N1P/P2Q1PPB/R4RK1 w - - 0 15"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 1.dxe5 Nd7 Black will get back their pawn with ...Nxe5 and be relieved that White's impressive center has been torn apart.

After 1.d5! The Nc6 is sent to a bad square and leaves the Pe5 with insufficient defense, e.g. 1...Ne7 2.Nxe5 with a décisive advantage for White.